# Serialization of objects (created with xsd containing complextypes) returns complextype as element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I have an XSD that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Example1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Example2" type="Example2Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Example2Type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Using VS2010, I have turned this XSD into a class looking like this:

```
using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Xml.Schema;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public partial class Example1
    {

        private List<Example2Type> example2Field;

        public Example1()
        {
            this.example2Field = new List<Example2Type>();
        }

        public List<Example2Type> Example2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.example2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.example2Field = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Example2Type
    {

        private int field1Field;

        private int field2Field;

        public int Field1
        {
            get
            {
                return this.field1Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.field1Field = value;
            }
        }

        public int Field2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.field2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.field2Field = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I now want to create some objects using the above classes. I do this with the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example1 test = new Example1();
            test.Example2 = new List<Example2Type>();
            test.Example2.Add(new Example2Type());
            test.Example2[0].Field1 = 2;

            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(test.GetType());
            x.Serialize(Console.Out, test);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

The XML that is now generated looks different than what I would expect. It now looks something like this:

```
<Example1>
  <Example2>
    <Example2Type>
      <Field1></Field1>
      <Field2></Field2>
    </Example2Type>
  </Example2>
</Example1>
```

Why is the Example2Type element added here and how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I had to add an extra attribute on the Example1 Class like this:

```
        [XmlElement("Example2")]
        public List<Example2Type> Example2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.example2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.example2Field = value;
            }
        }
```